# How can I subtract two values from edittext on runtime using textchangedlistener

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to subtract two values from EditText and display on the third EditText, if I make changes to anyone of the two EditText than it must reflect on the third EditText.

I have implemented a code but its not working.

```
package com.example.bipinp.mithun;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public  class DailyEntry extends AbstractActivity implements TextWatcher {
    private Button btnsbmtentry;
    private Spinner spiner2;
    private EditText milkcaret,amount,amountp,prevbal,currentBal,totalBal;
    DatabaseHelper mydb;
    int amnt,amntp,sub;
    String sAmnt,sAmntp,sumvalue;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_daily_entry);
        mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);


        btnsbmtentry=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsubmitentry);
        spiner2=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        milkcaret=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt1_de);
        amount=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt2_de);
        amountp=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt3_de);
        prevbal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt4_de);

        totalBal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt4_deTotBal);
        amount.addTextChangedListener(this);
        amountp.addTextChangedListener(this);

        adddata2();
        loadspinner();
        spiner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String pos = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                String bale = mydb.balance(pos);
                prevbal.setText(bale);

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

    }

    private void loadspinner() {
        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        List<String> labels = db.getAllLabels();
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,labels);
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spiner2.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }

    private void adddata2() {
        btnsbmtentry.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                boolean insertdata2 = mydb.insertdata2(spiner2.getSelectedItem().toString(),milkcaret.getText().toString(),amount.getText().toString(),amountp.getText().toString(),totalBal.getText().toString());
                if (insertdata2)
                    Toast.makeText(DailyEntry.this, "Record Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else
                    Toast.makeText(DailyEntry.this, "Databse Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        prevbal=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt4_de);
        currentBal = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt4_deCurrB);

        sAmnt = amount.getText().toString();
        sAmntp = amount.getText().toString();
        try {
            amnt = Integer.parseInt(sAmnt);
            amntp = Integer.parseInt(sAmntp);
            sub = amnt-amntp;
        }catch (NumberFormatException e){

        }
        sumvalue = String.valueOf(sub);
        currentBal.setText(sumvalue);

    }
}
```

Comment: may be you are getting exception there. check exception.

Comment: instead of trying inside afterTextChanged, try onTextChanged to achieve desire functionality

Comment: what it is not working? Do you have something written in the result editText?

Comment: First, when setting value sAmntp , your are setting same value as sAmnt with amount.getText() instead of amountp.getText()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update this line in AfterTextChanged:

```
sAmnt = amount.getText().toString();
sAmntp = amount.getText().toString();
```

to:

```
sAmnt = amount.getText().toString();
sAmntp = amountp.getText().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this code. its work for me**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextWatcher {

int iEditWages;
int iEditMoneySpent;
int iSubtract;
String sEditWages;
String sEditMoneySpent;
String sTotalLeftToSpend;
EditText EditWages;
EditText EditMoneySpent;
TextView TotalLeft;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EditMoneySpent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TotalSpentNumber);
    EditWages = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TotalWagesNumber);
    EditMoneySpent.addTextChangedListener(this);
    EditWages.addTextChangedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
        int after) {

}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    EditWages = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TotalWagesNumber);
    EditMoneySpent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TotalSpentNumber);
    TotalLeft = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TotalViewNumber);

    sEditWages = EditWages.getText().toString();
    sEditMoneySpent = EditMoneySpent.getText().toString();
    try {
        iEditWages = Integer.parseInt(sEditWages);
        iEditMoneySpent = Integer.parseInt(sEditMoneySpent);
        iSubtract = iEditWages - iEditMoneySpent;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    }

    sTotalLeftToSpend = String.valueOf(iSubtract);
    TotalLeft.setText(sTotalLeftToSpend);

}
```